# how to add custom colored circle ripple with circle mask when not rippled

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-theme, ripple

I want to add a ripple to my ImageView:

API +21

1. custom colored (one color for light theme, other color to dark theme)
2. circle mask

API -21 (optional):

1. custom colored (one color for light theme, other color to dark theme)

I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/google_blue200">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="@color/google_red200"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</ripple>
```

However, I want the ripple color to be chosen by the theme
and I want the circle mask to be transparent (when there is no ripple).

[image]

I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/MyRippleColor">
  <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="?attr/backgroundColor"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</ripple>
```

However I don't see the ripple.

Answer (score 0):

This xml helped me understand what's mask, background items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/myColor">
  <!-- Use this to define the shape of the ripple effect (rectangle, oval, ring or line). The color specified here isn't used anyway -->
  <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="ring">
      <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
      <!-- This color is needed to be set - doesn't affect anything -->
      <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</ripple>
```